# While-loop with two values

Tags: java, while-loop

i'm a beginner trying to understand how to write a while loop code that write out numbers in order and how many depends on the loop. For example loop(3,6) results in 3456. This is my try this far

```
public static void loop(int start, int end){

int loop = 1;
while( loop <= start && end < runLoop ){
     System.out.print( start + end ) ;
loop = loop+1;
    
   }
}
```

Comment: What is `runLoop` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `start` directly, until it reaches `end`:

```
public static void loop(int start, int end){
   while(start <= end){
      System.out.print(start);
      start++;    
   }
}
```